# How to type es6 generators with flow

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6, generator, flowtype

I have the following (simplified) code in my react-native app (I think react-native is irrelevant, but this is the context I found the error in).

I am trying to define the type of `mystring` and `gen` to keep `flow` happy, but the only solution I have found is `string|void` as below. The code below itself does not return any errors with flow, but as soon as I use `mystring` elsewhere, I get errors because a `string` is expected, not `void`. I've played around with a variety of combinations, but no luck.

How should I amend this code to fix the error?

```
// @flow
import * as React from 'react';

type State = {
    mystring: string|void,
};

type genType = Generator<string, void, void>;

export default class Example extends React.Component<{}, State> {
    constructor(props: {}) {
        super(props);
        this.gen = this.makeGenerator();
        const { value } = this.gen.next();
        this.state = {
            mystring: value,
        };
    }

    gen: genType;

    * makeGenerator(): genType {
        yield 'somestring';
    }

    render() {
        const { mystring } = this.state;
        return mystring.charAt(0);
    }
}
```

#### Edit:

When running `flow` on the code above, the last line (this is an example to force flow to think of `mystring` as a string):

```
Cannot call mystring.charAt because property charAt is missing in undefined [1].
 [1]  5│     mystring?: string,
```

Comment: What about define your `state` as interface and not a type and `mystring` as optional? I mean `mystring?: string`. I don't understand your usage of void

Comment: `this.gen.next()` might return `{value: undefined, done: true}` at the end, that's where the `void` type would come from. (I have no idea how to fix this)

Comment: @Milore I used `void` to cover the case where the generator is exhausted and returns nothing, but your `mystring?: string` is much cleaner. It still doesn't fix the problem though, as other uses of the variable as a string bring up `flow` errors. Can you give an example of what you mean by interface?

Comment: I usually define state and props of components as `interface IState {...}` but I just read an article about differences from using `type` as you did, and it turns out that's pretty the same. Can you post the exact error you get when using mystring elsewhere?

Comment: Ok, I don't fully understand you question. Using Typescript means you're gonna handle types both in definition and usages of all variables or whatever you're talking about. Clearly, in this case you have to face the fact that mystring could be undefined and you can't deal with it in that case. Just condition your return, for example `return mystring && mystring.charAt(0);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reference type type parameters to `Generator` look like this:

```
interface Generator<+Yield,+Return,-Next>
```

And when you call `next()` you get a result of this type:

```
type IteratorResult<+Yield,+Return> =
  | { done: true, +value?: Return }
  | { done: false, +value: Yield };
```

You can see in the `done: true` case Flow assumes that the `value` property in the result might be absent. This means that no matter how you type your generator, Flow assumes that the type of `value` might be `void` in that case. But in the `done: false` case Flow will use whatever type you specify as the `Yield` type of the generator. So you can check the value of `done` to refine the type of `value` like this:

```
const result = this.gen.next();
if (!result.done) {
  this.state = {
      mystring: result.value,
  };
}
```

The check for `!result.done` refines the type of `result` to `{ done: false, +value: Yield }`, which gives the type `string` for `value`, with no possibility for a `void` value.

With that change you can update the state type to remove `void` from the type union for `mystring`:

```
type State = {
    mystring: string,
};
```

The definitions for `Generator` and `IteratorResult` above come from Flow's standard type definitions which you can see here:

https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/master/lib/core.js

Comment: This works in that it removes the `flow` error on the `mystring: value,` line, but the line where I use `mystring` still gives me the same error. The way I'm assigning `mystring` means that in a different function, I don't have access to `result.done` so I can't refine the type the same way. Is it a limitation of `flow`?

Comment: I should have said that in addition to the check on `done` you will want to change the state type from `mystring: string|void` to `mystring: string`. You will also need to initialize the state with a default value for `mystring` if you want to avoid any type casts.

Comment: Great, this works! I should have figured the latter part by myself... Interestingly, if I use destructuring to get the yield value from the generator like `const { done, value } = this.gen.next()` then the assignment to `mystring` gives an error with flow, but it works fine the way you've written it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @LaurentS Yes, type narrowing does not work across multiple variables. If you keep `done` and `value` in one `result` object when you check `done` Flow narrows the type of that object, which in turn narrows the type of the `value` property. If you destructure `done` and `value` into two variables Flow does not have a mechanism to keep track of the connection between them.